# Efficient way of filling character

Tags: actionscript-3

I was thinking the fastest way of building a string with a fill char.define a function:

```
fillString('A',12); // return 'AAAAAAAAAAAA'
```

A simple loop could do this, but it's not very fast if I want to fill millions characters.

Is this the fastest way of combining string in actionscript?

```
array.join('');
```

If so, the first you need to build an array first,that would consume too much space.

Once I was thinking a [stringbuffer class](http://code.google.com/p/as3-commons/source/browse/trunk/as3-commons-lang/src/main/actionscript/org/as3commons/lang/StringBuffer.as?r=242) but I think it would be slower than using String directly.

Comment: Please tell me if the syntax is correct or I need to fix something to make the answer consistent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably not the correct actionscript syntax, but you should get the idea:

```
public function fillString(filler:String, count:integer):String {
    var result:String = filler;
    while (result.length <= count/2)
        result += result;
    return result+result.substr(0,count-result.length);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the fastest way to join strings, [this](http://jacksondunstan.com/articles/1790) article has some benchmarks:

http://jacksondunstan.com/articles/1790

Basically, just using bigString = stringA + stringB does the job, but it is possible to get some speed improvement using a ByteArray trick.

By the way, jacksondunstan.com is a great source for getting solid scientific data about AS3 performance in general.